# How to conditionally choose on instantiation which overriding method to call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a series of classes that inherit from each other as such. A `Base` class which defines the method but does not implement. That class is subclassed by another that does implement the method (`SubWithRun`). What I want to do, and have demonstrated through the `SubWithSpecificRun` class, is override the `_run` method.

Easy enough, but how can I conditionally decide which `_run` method to call when `SubWithSpecificRun` is instantiated? By default it will run the most specific one. Given some condition, I want to run `SubWithSpecificRun.run()` or the next level on the inheritance tree, i.e. `SubWithRun.run()`

```py
class Base():
    def _run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def run(self):
        self._run()

class SubWithRun(Base):
    def _run(self):
        print('Implementing run method')

class SubWithSpecificRun(SubWithRun):
    def _run(self):
        print('Implementing specific run method')
```

In essence, what I'm after is something like this:

```py
SubWithSpecificRun().run() == 'Implementing specific run method'
SubWithSpecificRun(use_specific=False).run() == 'Implementing run method'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would provide a `run` that uses either `self._run` or `super()._run`:

```
class SubWithSpecificRun(SubWithRun):
    def __init__(self, use_specific=True, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.use_specific = use_specific
    def run(self):
        if self.use_specific:
            return self._run()
        else:
            return super()._run()
    def _run(self):
        print('Implementing specific run method')

SubWithSpecificRun().run() # 'Implementing specific run method'
SubWithSpecificRun(use_specific=False).run() # 'Implementing run method'
```

This is an unusual pattern, and might be more complicated a solution than you actually need.  It would probably be better if you had some factory function that returned either `SubWithRun` or `SubWithSpecificRun` instances depending on the value  passed in.

Comment: Your solution is what I just came up with myself. I think a factory is the appropriate design solution, though.